# Display data as user level

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I have a calendar where users are going to register reminders and tasks, now I would like each user to see only their own tasks. Each task created is already associated with the user as I will be showing below, for this system I am using Codeigniter + FullCalendar (javascript), it follows my codes and images for better understanding:

Agenda:

View:

```
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function(){
        $("#nomeEvento").autocomplete({
          source: "clientes/get_cliente", // path to the method
          appendTo: $("#new_event")
        });
    }); 
  </script>

  <script>
  $(function(){
      $('.form-control.date').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          language: 'pt-BR',
          todayHighlight: true
      });
   });
  </script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/getEvents', 
  function(data){
  alert(data);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      locale: 'pt-br',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      editable: true,
      events: $.parseJSON(data),

      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc){
        var id = event.id;
        var fi = event.start.format();
        var ff = event.end.format();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/updateEvents",
        {
          id:id,
          inicio:fi,
          fim:ff,
        },
        function(data){
          if(data == 1){
            alert('Evento atualizado');
          }else{
            alert('Evento Nao atualizado')
          }
        });    
      },

      eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        var id = event.id;
        var fi = event.start.format();
        var ff = event.end.format();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/updateEvents",
        {
          id:id,
          inicio:fi,
          fim:ff,
        },
        function(data){
          if(data == 1){
          //alert('Evento atualizado');
        }else{
         // alert('Evento não atualizado')
        }

        });  
      },

      // eventClick: function(event,jsEvent, view){
      //   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event.id);
      //  }

      eventRender: function(event, element,data){
        var el = element.html();
        element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" + el + "</div><div class='closeee' style='color:red; text-align:right;'>X</div>");

        element.find('.closeee').click(function(){
          if(!confirm("Excluir registro ??")){
            revertFunc();
          }else{
                var id = event.id
                $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/deleteEvents",
                {
                  id:id,
                },
                function(data){
                  if(data == 1){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('deleteEvents', event.id);
                  //alert('Tarefa Excluida');
                }else{
                 //alert('Tarefa não Excluida')
                }

                }); 
              }
          });
      },

      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
        $('#id').html(event.id);
        $('#mtitulo').html(event.title);
        $('#autor').html(event.autor);
        $('#inicioEdit').val(event.start);
        $('#importanciaEdit').val(event.impor);
        $('#descricaoEventoEdit').val(event.text);
        $('#modalEvento').modal();
      },

    });
  });
});

$(function(){
      $('.form-control.date').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          language: 'pt-BR',
          todayHighlight: true
      });
   });

</script>



</head>


<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendar2 extends CI_controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('calendar2Model', 'model', TRUE);
    } 

    public function index(){
        $this->template->set('title', 'Agenda');
        $this->template->load('layout', 'calendar_v.php');
        //$this->load->view('calendar_v.php');
    }

    public function getEvents(){
        $data = $this->model->get_events();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function updateEvents(){
        $param['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
        $param['inicio'] = $this->input->post('inicio');
        $param['fim'] = $this->input->post('fim');
        $r =  $this->model->updateEvents($param);
        echo json_encode($r);
    }

    public function updateEvents2(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        /* Define as tags onde a mensagem de erro será exibida na página */
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span>', '</span>');

        /* Aqui estou definindo as regras de validação do formulário, assim como 
           na função inserir do controlador, porém estou mudando a forma de escrita */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mtitulo', 'Nome', 'required|max_length[40]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('autor', 'Autor', 'trim|required|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inicioEdit', 'Data', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('importanciaEdit', 'importancia', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricaoEventoEdit', 'Descricao', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');

        /* Executa a validação e caso houver erro chama a função editar do controlador novamente */
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> preencha todos os campos antes de salvar </div>");
                redirect('clientes');
        } else 
            /* Senão obtém os dados do formulário */
            $data['idevento'] = $this->input->post('nomeEvento');
            $data['nomeEvento'] = $this->input->post('mtitulo');
            $data['inicio'] = $this->input->post('inicioEdit');
            $data['fim'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('inicioEdit'). ' + 1 day'));
            $data['user'] = $this->input->post('autor');    
            $data['importancia'] = $this->input->post('importanciaEdit');   
            $data['descricaoEvento'] = $this->input->post('descricaoEventoEdit');

            /* Executa a função atualizar do modelo passando como parâmetro os dados obtidos do formulário */
            if ($this->model->updateEvents2($data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-success'> Cliente editado com sucesso</div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao editar cliente</div>");
            }
        }


    public function deleteEvents(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $r = $this->model->deleteEvents($id);
        echo json_encode($r);
    }

    public function new_event(){

        $this->template->set('title', 'Nova tarefa');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        /* Define as tags onde a mensagem de erro será exibida na página */
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span>', '</span>');

        /* Define as regras para validação */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nomeEvento', 'Nome', 'required|max_length[40]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inicio', 'Data de inicio', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('importancia', 'Prioridade', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricaoEvento', 'descricaoEvento', 'trim|required|max_length[150]');

        /* Executa a validação e caso houver erro chama a função index do controlador */
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-warning'> preencha todos os campos antes de salvar </div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            /* Senão, caso sucesso: */
        } else {

            /* Recebe os dados do formulário (visão) */
            $data['nomeEvento'] = $this->input->post('nomeEvento');
            $data['inicio'] = $this->input->post('inicio');
            $data['fim'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('inicio'). ' + 1 day'));
            $data['user'] = $this->input->post('user'); 
            $data['importancia'] = $this->input->post('importancia');   
            $data['descricaoEvento'] = $this->input->post('descricaoEvento');   


            /* Chama a função inserir do modelo */
            if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-success'> Lembrete salvo com sucesso</div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao salvar Lembrete </div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Model:

```
<?php

class calendar2Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_events(){
        $this->db->select('idevento id, inicio start, fim end,descricaoEvento text, user autor,importancia impor ,cnome title');
        $this->db->from('eventos');
        $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.ccod = eventos.nomeEvento');
        return $this->db->get()->result();

    }   

    function inserir($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('eventos', $data);
    }

    function updateEvents($param) {
        $campos = array(
                'inicio' => $param['inicio'],
                'fim' => $param['fim']
            );

        $this->db->where('idevento', $param['id']);
        $this->db->update('eventos', $campos);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
            return 1;
        } else{
            return 0;
            }       
        }

    function deleteEvents($id){
        $this->db->where('idevento', $id);
        $this->db->delete('eventos');
        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
            return 1;
        } else{
            return 0;
            }       
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any clear attempt at a solution here. It would also be helpful if you consolidated the code to what is relevant, there is a lot going on here.

Comment: Yes i'am working on that for 4 months man and i'm not asking for someone do for me i'm asking for someone give me one away to follow.

Comment: well the code on server which is compiling the list of events should get given the current User ID as a parameter (I don't know where this comes from, the Session maybe?), and only return the events for that user when it sends the response. BTW your code has a structural problem. You load the events, and then load the calendar containing those events. This is back to front, you should load the calendar, and then specify the `events` property as a function which loads the events. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ ...

Comment: ... that way, the calendar will only load the events relevant to the dates actually being displayed (as long as your server method correctly filters the events according to the "start" and "end" dates being supplied to it). This is more efficient - when the view/date changes, the calendar will automatically fetch only the extra events it needs. The way you have it now, you load _all_ your events up front. After a few years of use, this could be a lot of data, most of which will never actually be viewed (who looks at tasks from 4 years ago??)